# Remove similar tweets in an array with javascript & underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I am working on a simple twitter bot and need to get rid of similar tweets in search results.
how can I remove similar results in an array? Can I just do this using **underscore** and **string-similarity** modules ?
I am cleaning up the result as in the following example.

```js
const tweets = [
  "32 Things You're Doing Wrong With Your Website Design https://t.co/**** #Webdesign #WebsiteDesign… https://t.co/***",
  "How to Deal With Image Heavy Website Design https://t.co/*** #WebDesign #WebsiteDesign #PageLoadSpeed https://t.co/***",
  "How to Score a Perfect 100% on Google PageSpeed #Insights https://t.co/*** #Google #PageSpeed #Webdesign https://t.co/***",
  "How to Score a Perfect 100% on Google #PageSpeed Insights https://t.co/*** #Google #WebDesign https://t.co/***",
  "How to Score a Perfect 100% on #Google PageSpeed Insights https://t.co/*** #PageSpeed #WebApp https://t.co/***",
  "Hello Web Design launches today! Learn design fundamentals and shortcuts aimed at non-designers.… https://t.co/***",
  "How to Deal With Image Heavy Website Design https://t.co/*** #WebDesign #WebsiteDesign #PageLoadSpeed https://t.co/***",
  "#Drupal 8’s new upgrade path is a major reason organizations should consider migrating sooner rather than later”… https://t.co/***",
];
```

Comment: What is the criteria for deciding when two or more tweets are similar?

Comment: Hey jcarapia, 

I thought to use the "string-similarity" module for this. if you examine the code in the link, I think **0.75** and above can be considered similar. Of course, there may be another way you can. [sample code](http://requirebin.com/?gist=b152931ebdb4fd8d24a07f1271669899)